# Having RxJS observable active for certain time

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a FormControl for which I want to have a 'statusChanges' observable that should be deactivated after 2 seconds or after receiving the first emit whichever is earlier.

The below example deactivates the observable after receiving the first emit. But, it will be active for long time when there is no statusChanges for the FormControl:

```
this.formControl
  .statusChanges.pipe(first())
  .subscribe(() => {
    // DO MY STUFF
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The RxJS operator [`timeout`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout) exists exactly for such scenarios. It'll emit an error if the source observable hasn't emitted for a give amount of time.

```js
export const LIMIT = 2000;    // <-- time in ms

this.formControl.statusChanges.pipe(
  first(),
  timeout(LIMIT)
).subscribe(() => {
  // DO MY STUFF
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
this.formControl
  .statusChanges
  .pipe(
    first(),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    // DO MY STUFF
  });

timer(2000);
  .subscribe(() => {
     this.destroy$.next();
     this.destroy$.complete();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution it to merge a timer and take the first from whichever emits.

```ts
merge(
  this.formControl.statusChanges,
  timer(2000)
).pipe(
  first()
).subscribe(() => {
  // DO STUFF
});
```

Comment: In this case the subscription `next` callback could receive the value `0` if the `timer` emits first. Which may or may not be desirable if the callback expects an emission from the `statusChanges` observable.